# Red Blood Cell Color Image Segmentation

Tags: matlab, python, image-segmentation, object-recognition

[image]

[image]

I want to segment this Red Blood Cell Image on HSI color space.I want to try the Otsu Method but from what I read that method work only on Grayscale image.Do you have any suggestion for suitable image segmentation on those red blood cell image ?
[EDIT]
This is what i want to achieve(Segmented Blood Cell)
[image: Segmented Blood Cell Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **Matlab**:

You might try converting your image to greyscale first with

```
greycells = rgb2gray(rgbcells);
```

where rgbcells contains the color image of your cells (see [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html)).

Then use Otsu's threshold on the greyscale image like so

```
threshcells = graythresh(greycells);
```

like so (see [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html)).

**EDIT**
After OP explained what image should be the resulting image.

**Using: FIJI** (formerly ImageJ)

I am still not 100% sure as to which images you finally want to obtain. It seems like you only want to see the cells with the many purple dots (sorry, I am not a biologist myself) inside them and completely remove the others. For this attempt at a solution I use FIJI, but the principle can be easily applied in Python / Matlab, you name it...

Your images are somewhat different, because in the first image the other cells pretty much have the same color as the one in the middle (that you want to segment probably). In the second image the other cells are much lighter.

Let us look at the second image first:

*Converting to HSI*

Use the [Color Transformer 2 Plugin](http://www.russellcottrell.com/photo/colorTransformer2.htm) to convert the images to HSI using the options "From Colorspace: sRGB" and "To Colorspace: HSI". Looking at the channels we can see that S and I carry pretty much the same information. So let's stick with the I channel. It looks like this: [image: I channel of second image].

*Selecting a Threshold*

Now we use the useful "Auto Threshold" (Image->Adjust->Auto Threshold) feature of Fiji on this channel. Clip the image from the HSI stack and convert it to 16 bit first. Use the option "Try All", also check "Ignore White" and uncheck "white objects on black background". Now we can see a whole panel of different thresholding algorithms applied to this image. It looks like this:

[image: Different thresholding methods for Image 2 (I channel)]

You can see that many thresholding methods do what you want. Among them Otsus method (as you suggested) and MaxEnt. Now that we know MaxEnt or Otsus thresholding works for this image lets do the same thing again (meaning AutoThreshold), but instead of "Try All" we select "MaxEnt" as our threshold of choice (you'll see below why MaxEnt). Then we invert the threshold and overlay it on the image and we end up with:

[image: Thresholded image 2]

*Now for the first image*

Here we can do exactly the same. Repeating the steps, we end up with an I channel like this:

[image: I channel of image 1]

The other cells are very well visible here. This is also true for the other channels. I have also plotted the histogram. The left hump corresponds to the wihte background, the right hump to pretty much all cells. This will be important in the next step.

Now try all thresholds again like above and we will see this:

[image]

You see that Otsus threshold separates the cells from the background, but does not give you the cell in the middle that you want. Look at the Histogram: due to the way Otsus method is designed ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method)) it will seperate these two clusters. Which is not what you want (as I understand) in this case. But MaxEnt(Maximum Entropy) does. So use the MaxEnt threshold as above.

You will end up with this:

[image]

**SUMMARY**
This is my processing chain:

- Do HSI transform
- Apply MaxEnt threshold to the I channel
- Use the binary mask on the RGB image again to clip out the relevant parts

**OUTLOOK**
If you are not satisfied with the results, then play around with different thresholds. Ultimately changing the colorspance and thresholding are powerful but very low tech ways of image segmentation. You might be interested in more sophisticated ways. For a software suite catered especially to cell biologists check out [Cell Profiler](http://cellprofiler.org/). Former colleagoues have used it and were very happy with it.

**LITERATURE**
Maximum Entropy Threshold: Wong et al: "A gray-level threshold selection method based on maximum entropy principle",  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/35351

Comment: my professor said to do the segmentation on color image(HSI color space)(Without Converting to Grayscale) but he didnt give me guidance on what method to use.Do you have any idea any method that working for color image segmentation ?

Comment: @JuliusPermana Have you tried looking at the individual HIS channels to see if you can apply your thresholding there (the individual channels are grayscale images again)?

Comment: Hi,I already edit my question.That third picture is my goal of image segmentation.Do you have any suggestion for method that is suitable for that ?

Comment: @JuliusPermana check out my edits and see if they are useful to you.

Comment: @JuliusPermana did the edits help you?

Comment: How to convert to 16 bit image ?I already convert the image from RGB to HSI using color transformer 2

Comment: First you select the image and then  use Image->Adjust-Brightnes and contrast. Then you press set with min 0 and max 1 and apply it to the image. This adjusts the dynamic range after conversion. Then go to Image->Type -> 16bit

Comment: Thanks for your guidance its already succesful until threshold using Maximum Entropy.But you said  Then we invert the threshold and overlay it on the image and we end up with: how can we do this ?

Comment: @JuliusPermana Do this: first select the black and white threshold image and click Edit -> Invert. This should make the cells black and the background white. Then select your original RGB cell image again (you may have to re-open it). Now click Image->Overlay->Add Image... and in the dialoge select the name of the threshold image. In the dialog check the box "Zero transparent" and then OK. Finally click Image->Overlay->Flatten to finalize the image.

If you found this helpful, be so kind to accept my answer using the green checkbox next to the up and downvote buttons.

Comment: @JuliusPermana Also familiarize yourself with ImageJ / FIJI because it is a powerful tool.

One final suggestion: I still don't see the benefit of going to HSI color space. Try it out: convert the RGB image to greyscale by just selecting it and clicking Image->Type->16 bit. Then you can directly apply the thresholding operations. For your images it makes virtually no difference. Ask your professor why he insisted on the HSI transformation...